# Issues with elasticSearch geoPoint

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch 1.1.0, and trying to use the geodistance filter.

Here is my mapping

```
{
"dynamic": "true",
"numeric_detection": true,
"properties": {
    "address": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
            "city": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "country": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "location": {
                "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "postcode": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "region": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "state": {
                "type": "string"
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my document

```
"address": {
    "postcode": "29004",
    "city": "Málaga",
    "state": "Málaga",
    "region": "Málaga",
    "country": "espagne",
    "location": {
        "lat": 36.68676,
        "lon": -4.49028
    }
}
```

(The mapping was created before indexing any document, and the document is well indexed). But when a try to fetch this annonce with the following query string

```
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {

            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "200km",
                "address.location": {
                    "lat": 36.68676,
                    "lon": -4.49028
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I got no results.. I can not understand why. Am I doing something wrong ? Thanks for your help :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , I forgot to set the long_lat mapping option ... https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-geo-point-type.html#_mapping_options

Comment: What did your final structure look like?